# Cannot mount Veracrypt partition on Linux Mint (Metadata kept in Windows cache)

Tags: linux, windows, mount, veracrypt

I'm getting the following error message:

```
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/mapper/veracrypt8': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

I'm aware that this problem has something to do with Windows' hibernation/fast startup, and is similar to this question and answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation/.  However, I've already tried those solutions, and have had no success.  I can mount the partition just fine in Windows, and I can mount it in read-only mode in Linux.

I have Windows 10 and Linux Mint 18 installed.  The partition in question does not have an operating system on it, and is the only partition on its disk.

What I've tried:

- Disabling Fast Startup in Windows
- Mounting the partition in Windows, then triggering a reboot from Windows and going into Linux instead of back into Windows
- Checking that there are no Windows page files set up on the partition.
- Disabling hibernation in Windows with `powercfg /h off`.
- Checking that there is no `hiberfile.sys` on the partition (both from Windows with system files shown and from Linux in read-only mode).
- Telling Veracrypt in Linux to use `-t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile` as its mount options.
- Unlocking (but not mounting) the partition with Veracrypt in Linux, then trying the command `sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o remove_hiberfile /dev/mapper/veracrypt8 /media/veracrypt8`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens when Windows hibernation data is present on encrypted partition itself (not on partition containing encrypted volume file).

This solution should work in every distro, just make sure you have ntfsfix installed.

1. Mount VeraCrypt volume with "Filesystem -> Do not mount" option checked (click "Options" button to see this option when asked for password).
   [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WqY8.png)
2. Right-click volume on the list and select "Properties". "Virtual Device" property shows the device you need to fix using ntfsfix.
3. Run the following command:

   sudo ntfsfix [virtual-device]

Where [virtual-device] is the path you have seen under "Virtual Device", for example "/dev/mapper/veracrypt1".

4. Remount VeraCrypt volume, unchecking "Do not mount" option.

Comment: Well, this solution mostly worked for me.  I now have full use of the partition in Linux, but when I tried mounting it again in Windows, it suggested that I run a `chkdsk`, which found no errors.  However, I can no longer see anything on the partition in Windows Explorer.  Strangely, other programs (including other file explorers) have no problems.

Comment: Windows Explorer is now working fine with the partition.  I don't know why, since I haven't done anything to fix it, but everything's working now. :D

Comment: Thank you so much for this. ntfsfix for me only worked with those parameters: `sudo ntfsfix -b -d "/dev/mapper/veracrypt1"`

Comment: When using the command line, this is the equivalent to the do not mount option in the filesystem: sudo veracrypt -t -k "" --protect-hidden=no --filesystem=none --mount /path_to_encrypted_media /media/mount_point

For dismounting the volumes sudo veracrypt -d

Then the sudo ntfsfix /dev/mapper/veracrypt1 worked perfectly, then the volume mounted fine! Although only for root, I still cannot manage to make it visible to nonroot users.